# defining multiple variables to an empty list in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create and assign 10 variables, only differenciated by their index, all as empty lists within a `for` loop.

The ideal output would be to have `agent_1 = [], agent_2 = [], agent_n = []`

I know I could write this all out but thought I should be able to create a simple loop. The main issue is assigning the empty list over each iteration

```py
for i in range(1,10):
    agent_ + i = []
```

Comment: When your trying to make a bunch of variables like `agent_1` `agent_2` it’s a sign you should be using a list instead and using `agent[1]` etc.

Comment: Don't do this even if you find a way. Use a 2 dimensional list instead, i.e. `agent = []` before the loop and then `agent[i] = []` inside, and then access to elements using `agent[n][m]`.

Comment: 1. Python doesn't care about the name of the variable, foo =1 and baz = 1, don't matter, so it will not let you do this.
2. As many already mentioned a 2-D list is the way to do it.

Comment: @Selcuk nice idea, I wrote this but seems like something is lightly off: agent , value = [] , []
for i in range(1,10):
    agent.append(value) 
print(agent[0][2])

Comment: @madman You can post this as a new question explaining what is wrong with it.

Comment: got it sorted out, @Selcuk thanks! 

b = 1, 40;
agent_basket = [[ ] for basket in range(b)]
agent_basket

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use dict object with keys equal to agent_i.

```
dic = {}
for i in range(1,10):
    dic["agent_" + str(i)] = []

// access the dic directly and iterating purpose also just iterate through the dictionary.
print dic["agent_1"]
# iteration over the dictionary
for key,value in dic.items():
    print key,value
```

Here is the link to [code snippet](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/YNOmTocREP)

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible idea. I will let the code speak for itself:

```
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    globals()['agent_%d' % (i + 1)] = []
```

Answer (score -2):

```
a = {} 
for i in xrange(10):
    ab = "{}_{}".format("agent", i)
    a[ab] = []

print a
#OP 
{'agent_0': [], 'agent_1': [], 'agent_2': [], 'agent_3': [], 'agent_4': [], 'agent_5': [], 'agent_6': [], 'agent_7': [], 'agent_8': [], 'agent_9': []}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what your code does and why it's the right solution?